# How to check at what level/version is Db2 database?

Tags: migration, db2, db2-luw

On Linux x86_64 I installed Db2 v11.5.8.0 and I am in the process of upgrading instances and databases from v11.1 to v11.5.

We have several Linux machines and they have at least two Db2 versions installed: v11.1 and v11.5 and each database version has several instances and each instance several databases.

I can check:

- Db2 versions installed on Linux with: `db2ls`
- which Db2 version is applied to particular instance: `db2greg -dump | grep ^I`

But how to check in particular Db2 instance which databases were already upgraded with *db2 upgrade database <db_name>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in `sysibm.sysversions` table with SQL by creating appropriate queries depending on which detail you seek.

After you successfully run `upgrade database` the column VERSIONBUILDLEVEL will show a value that includes one of the tokens in the `db2level` output . Other columns have the date of the upgrade, versionnumber (e.g. 11.5.0.8) , authid (that performed the upgrade) etc.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need.